# SQL server slowdown

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql database and an application that runs on 2 different servers.  These servers are running sql server 7 and are running the same version of the application.

One of the servers has started slowing down how long it was processing files, so we upped the amount of RAM from 2GB to 4GB, but this didn't help.  All of the slow down occurs in the database as it goes through triggers to update tables.

It takes about 1.5 minutes for it to process a file (For reference, it takes the other server about 16 seconds to go through the same triggers and process a file).

I'm looking at the server that is taking forever and all of the metrics look good: There's enough ram (especially now that it's been upped to 4GB), the processor load is fine, etc etc.

Since it doesn't look like it's a resource issue and it's obviously not a trigger issue because both servers have exactly the same ones, I'm at a complete loss of what could be causing this...

Comment: Have you watched the execution in activity monitor to see if it has some waits or blocking?

Comment: @Dustin activity monitor probably doesn't exist for `SQL Server 7` @user What is the trigger code? Also what do you mean by processing a file?

Comment: SQL Server 7 might not use the extra RAM please take a look at this  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274750

Comment: @Martin - Sorry, by processing a file I just mean going through all of the triggers to update necessary tables/columns and creating the audit trail (the main functionality of the app is file transfer). @Beatles - On the slow server (1.5 minutes to go through a file) it's actually set to use 3.5GB of the 4GB of memory.  On the fast one (16 seconds to go through a file) it's set to use 2GB (out of the 2GB There)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know anything about sql server 7, so i'm jsut going to go off of what i know about 200/2005+

have you checked to make sure that the max memory setting is set to an appropriate amount for the new ram?

have you tried refreshing views?  [refreshing views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272829/why-do-sql-server-views-needs-to-be-refreshed-every-once-in-a-while)

have you made sure that the hardware, in all aspects, is the same on each server?

have you checked indexes/statistics?

Comment: I'd agree with this, except that I would put 'Check Statistics' at the top of the list. Check out the sp_updatestats command.